# How to change position of googlemap's myLocationButton in swift 3

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to place the myLocationButton in my iOS app at the top right corner but can't seem to find a way to do so. Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a navigation bar to the top of your storyboard for this view controller or its xib. If this view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller you can skip this step.

[image]

From there you can add Navigation items to either the left or right bar that can be controlled by your View Controller like any other object.

[image]

Well you can always place the button on the storyboard page and use auto constraints? You can also create the button programmatically to be at the top right button similar to this:

```
Let myLocationButton = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x:self.view.frame.size.width - (the width of your button), y: 0, width: (the width of your button), height: (the height of your button))
```

then add any other attributes you want to the button using dot syntax like text or an image. and then add it as a subview:

```
self.view.addSubview(myLocationButton)
```

Comment: I don't want to place it in the navigation bar, i want it to just be on the main view

Comment: Well, you could also use auto constraints in storyboard or add the button programatically. I have updated my answer above with the programatic solution.